# Get unique permission of list/libraries through sharepoint 2007 web services

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, web-services

Is there a way to get all the SharePoint list/library names having unique permission of a particular site collection using web services.

I am working on SharePoint 2007 site and hence web services will be of 2007.

Comment: Update:

WS_SiteData.SiteData ss = new WS_SiteData.SiteData();
            ss.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xx", "yyy");
            WS_SiteData._sListMetadata lstMetaData;
            WS_SiteData._sProperty[] lstFields;
            ss.GetList("Carrom Register", out lstMetaData,out lstFields);
            if(lstMetaData.InheritedSecurity == false)
            {   
                MessageBox.Show("false");
            }
I tried this but I am getting false for all lists with unique or non-unique permissions??

Comment: my mistake, The lists i was checking was having unique permissions. Its returning true for Non-unique one. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SpServices` to achieve this, it will happen in 2 steps:

1. Get all list names in an Array (below I'm logging it but you'll need to push it to an Array)

   ```
   $().SPServices({ 
       operation: "GetListCollection", 
       completefunc: function( xData, Status ) {
           console.log( Status );
           console.log( xData.responseText );

           $( xData.responseXML ).find("Lists > List").each(function() {
               var $node = $(this);

               console.log( $node.attr("Title") );
           });
       }});
   ```
2. Now loop through all the items of array one by one and use below script:

You will need to use the [SiteData service](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SiteData). A basic example:

```
$().SPServices({
      operation: "SiteDataGetList",
      strListName: "Announcements", //here you'll refer array value
      async: false,
      completefunc: function(xData, Status) {}
});
```

This will return a node sListMetadata. If the list inherits permissions it will have an attribute of `<InheritedSecurity>true</InheritedSecurity>`. If the list is using custom permissions, it will have a `<Permissions>` node and give all the permissions.

Comment: Any other alternative using Web services.. We have a SiteData Webservice as well but I was not able to get unique permissions.

Comment: What was the response?

Comment: Ok.. I guess I got a step closer. I used the Sitedata webservice as below as was able to get Inherited permission object as false in the metadata. Now I only have to figure out to check it. I guess I can go frm here. Thanks.. 
 WS_SiteData._sListMetadata lstMetaData;
            WS_SiteData._sProperty[] lstFields;
            ss.GetList("Announcements", out lstMetaData,out lstFields);
            foreach(WS_SiteData._sProperty field in lstFields)
            {

Comment: Cool, use the permission tag to get the permissions. Mark it as answered if it helped you:)

Comment: I tried with other lists wid unique n inherited permissions. but its returning false al the time?It shld return false only fr unique one lists.What wrong am i doing?:(

 WS_SiteData.SiteData ss = new WS_SiteData.SiteData();
            ss.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xx", "yyy");
            WS_SiteData._sListMetadata lstMetaData;
            WS_SiteData._sProperty[] lstFields;
            ss.GetList("Carrom Register", out lstMetaData,out lstFields);
            if(lstMetaData.InheritedSecurity == false)
            {   
                MessageBox.Show("false");
            }

Comment: So sorry.. I checked only for lists having unique permission. My mistake... Its returning true for inherited one.